# Using javascript function that gets innerHTML from webpage to get specific html content out of a String

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, web

So I have this function that gets innerHTML from the site I'm in:

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function(){ 
  alert(document.getElementById('hourbyhour_details').innerHTML);
};​
```

However that's not what I need, I want to get the innerHTML of another site I'm  not in. I can use a WebRequest and a StreamReader to read the source code of the page I want and store it in a String, is there a way to send this String to the function? Or Is there just another way to get specific content like that but from a remote site, and not necesarily the one I'm in?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to get around the same-origin policy to do this in Javascript. You can see more here:

[Same-origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

One way to get around this is JSONP, the other way is have a server-side script return the information you want from your domain. Good luck.

Comment: Oh well, better to know now than after a few hours of realizing that wasn't the correct way to do it.